# Set method cannot find symbol in extended class?

Tags: java, class, methods

Here's my code:

```
public class PTEmployee extends Employee
{
   private int nHours;
   private float wages;

public PTEmployee(String name, String ssn, String position, Date dateOfBirth,
                 float pay, int nHours, float wages)
{
    super(name,ssn,position,dateOfBirth,pay);
    nHours = nh;
    wages = w;
    pay = 0;
}
public void raise(float amount)
{
    wages = wages + amount;
    pay = nHours * wages;
}  
public void setNHours(int nh)
{
    nHours = nh;
}
public void setWages(float w)
{
    wages = w;
}
public int getNHours()
{
    return nHours;
}
public float getWages()
{
    return wages;
}
}
```

When I try to compile, it gives me the error: cannot find symbol's nh and w in the set methods:
nHours = nh;
wages = w;

Can anyone tell me why and how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: In your constructor the arguments are named `nHours` and `wages`, so the assignments should be `this.nHours=nHours; this.wages=wages;`

Comment: I would also like to point out that `pay = 0;` looks very suspicious as well. Can't be sure since I don't know what you have in `Employee` class.

Comment: voting to close this questions as a typographical error. Which is not useful to anyone else and thus off-topic

Answer (score 2):

For as far as I can see the problem is in your constructor and not in your setters. Parameters and used names don't match -> nh is nHours ( in params ) and w = wages (in params )

Change to constructor should be made to:

```
public PTEmployee(String name, String ssn, String position, Date dateOfBirth,
                 float pay, int nHours, float wages)
{
    super(name,ssn,position,dateOfBirth,pay);
    this.nHours = nHours;
    this.wages = wages;
    pay = 0;
}
```